# Distinguishable quantum states ("counterexample")

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

In the book *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* (Nielsen & Chuang) the section 2.2.4 discusses quantum distinguishability and arrives at the conclusion that if someone were to show me a set of states and give me one of them, I can only tell which one it is if the set is orthogonal. So I came up with a counterexample to this. Let's say we have these two states:
\begin{align}
|\psi_1\rangle & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)\\
|\psi_2\rangle & = |0\rangle \, .
\end{align}

If I make a measurement on the unknown state and the result is the eigenvalue associated with $|1\rangle$, I know with certainty that the given state was $|\psi_1\rangle$, so I was able to distinguish them even though they are not orthogonal.
Clearly there's something wrong with my thinking, but I can't tell what it is.

Comment: what if you got $0$?

Comment: You get one shot at telling what the state is and you have to be guaranteed correct.

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters; but in this example you also destroy the state you started with; so you no longer have it

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, so can't say for sure what the authors were thinking, but if I had to bet, I'd bet that @spaceisdarkgreen is exactly right.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Why don't you turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this protocol requires you to be able to distinguish them with a single measurement, on a single copy of the system; moreover, you're not allowed to fail, and you're not allowed to skip or give any non-committal answer.

This is why your protocol fails: if you're given $|\psi_1\rangle$, you have a 50% chance of getting the measurement outcome $|0\rangle$, in which case you don't know which one to choose and you're forced to provide an answer that might be wrong.

---

In general, the answer to quantum distinguishability problems can depend quite sensitively on the details of the formulation of the requirements on the protocol. Two other examples:

- You might be allowed an unlimited number of copies of the states to do your measurements (though you might want to keep the number of required copies to a minimum), in which case you can do [quantum state tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography) and provide very detailed answers about the given states.
- You might be given a single copy of the system, and you're not allowed to make mistaken identifications, but you allow the protocol to fail, i.e., to refuse to give an answer (often called *unambiguous discrimination*). In this case your measurement is OK but it can be optimized, and in the optimal case you can provide definite answers that it must be $|\psi_1\rangle$ or that it must be $|\psi_2\rangle$, no matter how similar the two are ─ but the closer they get, the more often the protocol fails to produce an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the book just has a higher standard for "distinguishable" than you do. Notice that in your example, you could not tell what state it was if you had measured a zero rather than a one. So you cannot guarantee to know what state it was in any outcome, only in the case that you "get lucky" and measure a one.